# Drawing a PESTEL diagram

Tags: diagrams, polygon

I'm new in LaTex and I'm trying to create a PESTEL diagram but I don't know what's the right approach. I would like something like this if it's possible:
[image: PESTEL diagram]

(I don't need to have the big letter, just the 6 parts with some text inside)

I tried with the Tikz package but don't know how to do it.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
[every node/.style={trapezium, trapezium angle=60, minimum width=10cm, draw, thick}]
  \node [rotate=0] {Politique};
  \node [rotate=60] {Economique};
  \node [rotate=120] {Socio-culturel};
  \node [rotate=180] {Technologique};
  \node [rotate=240] {Ecologique};
  \node [rotate=300] {Légal};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please feel free to add your trials-in-Tikz. Don't hesitate to describe your achievements and shortcomings. Thank you

Comment: Great, thank you. All you have left to do now is making the code complete, so it will compile when we copy and try it. Kindly have a look here for some hints: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that/10137#10137

Answer (score 6):

The [wheelchart](https://ctan.org/pkg/wheelchart) package, which I wrote, can be used.

The gap between the slices is obtained with the key `gap`.

The big letter is determined by the first variable, which is denoted by `\WCvarA`. These are used in the key `inner data`. The positioning of these big letters is determined by the keys `inner data angle pos` and `inner data pos`. The style is determined by the key `inner data style`.

The text in the middle is determined by the key `middle` and its style by the key `middle style`.

The key `radius` defines the inner and outer radius.

The inner and outer shape is determined by the keys `slices inner arc` and `slices outer arc`.

The start angle is determined by the key `start half`.

We set `value=1` so that each slice is the same size. We also set the key `data` empty.

The remaining text is determined by the key `wheel data`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=6pt,dvipsnames]{standalone}
\usepackage{wheelchart}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\sffamily
\wheelchart[
  data=,
  gap,
  inner data=\emph{\WCvarA},
  inner data angle pos=0.9,
  inner data pos=0.8,
  inner data style={white,font=\Huge},
  middle=LA FIRME ET\\SON MARCHÉ,
  middle style={font=\Large},
  radius={2}{10.5},
  slices inner arc={0}{0},
  slices outer arc={0}{0},
  start half,
  value=1,
  wheel data=\WCvarD\\\WCvarE,
  wheel data pos=0.5,
  wheel data style=\WCvarC
]{%
  É/Bittersweet/white/{\Large Économique}/Taux de croissance du PIB\\Taux d'inflation\\Taux d'intérêt nominal\\Taux de change des devises\\Pression fiscale\\Pouvoir d'achat\\des ménages\\\dots,
  S/Brown/white/{\Large Socio-}\\{\Large culturel}/Composantes démographiques\\Niveau de l'IDH\\Influences religieuses\\Qualité de l'éducation\\Immigration{/}émigration\\Évolution du coefficient\\de Gini\\\dots,
  T/SeaGreen/white/{\Large Technologique}/Niveau de R\&D\\Évolutions scientifiques\\Démocratisation technologique\\Subvention de la recherche\\Vitesse d'obsolescence\\Coût de l'innovation\\\dots,
  É/BurntOrange/black/{\Large Écologique}/Changements climatiques\\Conditions météorologiques\\Protection de l'environnement\\Propension au recyclage\\Énergies renouvelables\\Tendance à la croissance verte\\\dots,
  L/Magenta/white/{\Large Légal}/Sécurité juridique\\Protection de la propriété\\Flexibilité du droit social\\Réglementations\\professionnelles\\Fiabilité du droit\\des contrats\\Cohérence de la\\jurisprudence\\\dots,
  P/LimeGreen/black/{\Large Politique}/Conflits ou guerres\\Stabilité politique\\Politiques économiques\\Indice de corruption\\Élections imminentes\\Lobbying\\\dots%
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot but it's not working properly in my document. I tried in a new document and it's working except that the letters are all put in the middle.

Comment: @EdwinZAP The code in the answer requires version 2.0 of the wheelchart package. The version can be verified in the .log file, which should contain `wheelchart 2023/12/03 v2.0`. Version 2.0 can be downloaded from CTAN.

Comment: @EdwinZAP If there is still a problem after that, then the version of expl3 is not up to date enough. Then it is probably sufficient to put the following _before_ `\usepackage{wheelchart}`:

`\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_gset:Nn { Ne }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \str_case:nnF { enF }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_set:Nn { Ne }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \regex_match:nnTF { nVTF }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \str_case:nn { en }
\cs_set_eq:NN \cs_set:Npe \cs_set:Npx
\cs_set_eq:NN \cs_set:cpe \cs_set:cpx
\ExplSyntaxOff`

Comment: I'm using overleaf. I don't know if I can choose the package version. I will check that.